# Как сделать первичную отрисовку в окне в MFC в C++?

Tags: c++, mfc, окно, рисование

Здравствуйте!

У меня есть проект в MFC. При нажатии некоторой кнопки он открывает окно:

```
SomeWindow.DoModal();
```

Разумеется, `SomeWindow` - это класс обработчик некоторого окна, которое я создал в диалоге. Данный класс у меня унаследован от `CDialogEx`.
Мне требуется, чтобы при открытии этого окна отрисовывалась некоторая картинка.
Отрисовывание картинки я заключил в функцию:

```
void SomeWindow::ToStart();
```

Когда я эту функцию всовывал в конструктор, приложение не запускалось. Когда я вызвал эту функцию как-то так:

```
SomeWindow.DoModal();
SomeWindow.ToStart();
```

Тоже приходила ошибка.

**Вопрос:**

Как отрисовать первоначальную картинку нового окна? В какое место программы воткнуть функцию `ToStart()`, чтобы всё заработало?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я уже давно ничего не писал в MFC, но судя по моему старому проекту нужно в класс Вашего диалога добавить функции-обработчики событий WM_PAINT и WM_SIZE (при необходимости) (точное название событий тоже не помню, но должны быть функции типа OnPaint() и OnSize()). И вашу ToStart() соответственно, вызывать из OnPaint(). И еще, я бы этой функции (ToStart()) добавил входной параметр - указатель на DC (кажется, класса CDC), т.к. в OnPaint() у Вас будет объектом контекста CPaintDC, а в других местах - кажется, CClientDC.

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую рассмотреть подробнее.

Comment: Рассмотрел. Спасибо. Вы были правы. Нужно было добавить `WM_PAINT`